# При запуске программы выскакивает ошибка request eror

Tags: python, aiohttp

После запуска и перехода непосредственно на адрес http://127.0.0.1:8080/scan/192.168.0.1/1/10
На сервере выдается ошибка 505, также в логах программы(консоли) отображается request error.
Вот код программы:

```py
from aiohttp import web
import logging
import json
import asyncio


def catch_exception(func):
    async def decorated_function(ip, port, scan_loop):
        try:
            await func(ip, port, scan_loop)
            return [{"port": str(port), "state": "open"}]
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return [{"port": str(port), "state": "close"}]
    return decorated_function


@catch_exception
async def check_port(ip, port, scan_loop):
    conn = asyncio.open_connection(ip, port, loop=scan_loop)
    await asyncio.wait_for(conn, timeout=3)


async def run(ip, begin_port, end_port, scan_loop):
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(check_port(ip, p, scan_loop)) for p in range(begin_port, end_port)]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return responses


async def handle(request):
    ip = request.match_info.get('ip')
    begin_port = int(request.match_info.get('begin_port'))
    end_port = int(request.match_info.get('end_port'))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = await asyncio.ensure_future(run(ip, begin_port, end_port, loop))
    print(results)
    response_obj = {'data': results}

    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status=200)


def get_app():
    new_app = web.Application()
    new_app.router.add_get('/scan/{ip}/{begin_port}/{end_port}', handle)
    return new_app


# _________________________ pytest _____________________________________

def create_app(loop):
    test_app = get_app()
    return test_app


async def test_hello(aiohttp_client):
    client = await aiohttp_client(create_app)
    resp = await client.get('/scan/192.168.0.1/1/10')
    assert resp.status == 200
    data = await resp.text()
    dict_data = json.loads(data)
    assert type(dict_data['data']) is list

# _________________________ pytest _____________________________________


logger = logging.getLogger('aiohttp.access')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting!')
    web.run_app(get_app())
```

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_protocol.py", line 422, in _handle_request
    resp = await self._request_handler(request)
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 499, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\main.py", line 35, in handle
    results = await asyncio.ensure_future(run(ip, begin_port, end_port, loop))
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\main.py", line 25, in run
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\main.py", line 10, in decorated_function
    await func(ip, port, scan_loop)
  File "C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\aiohttp_server\main.py", line 20, in check_port
    await asyncio.wait_for(conn, timeout=3)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 47, in open_connection
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
TypeError: BaseEventLoop.create_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'
127.0.0.1 [17/Jun/2022:07:05:40 +0000] "GET /scan/192.168.0.1/1/10 HTTP/1.1" 500 335 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 YaBrowser/22.5.2.615 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: client.get('/scan/192.168.0.1/1/10') это так и задумано?

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса....

Comment: любой запрос по адресу должен начинаться "http://", a у вас явно не переменная.

Comment: я и делаю запрос по адресу "http://127.0.0.1:8080/scan/192.168.0.1/1/10 "

Comment: Есть какие-то варианты решения этой проблемы?